# Firebase modify childByAutoID

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to update child by auto id? This is how I have my chatroom setup but the problem is every time I update the user photo its never changed because the photo is assigned and received from the childByAutoId. Any Tips?

[image]

[image]

```
//Get Data from database resend to database
        if let userId = userID {
        ref.child("Users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

        let snapDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let username = snapDict?["Username"] as? String ?? ""
        let firebaseUserPhotoURL = snapDict?["photo_url"] as? String ?? ""
        let userRank = snapDict?["user_rank"] as? String ?? ""

        let now = Date()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        let nowString = dateFormatter.string(from: now)


        //Update general_room information about user
        ref.child("general_room").childByAutoId().setValue(["user_name": username, "uid": userId, "Message" : message, "time_stamp" : nowString, "photo_url" : firebaseUserPhotoURL])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update value in Firebase with childByAutoId?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714113/how-to-update-value-in-firebase-with-childbyautoid)

Comment: This is not a duplicate im lookng for an exact value in the key